# ver si coincide un valor de un diccionario con el valor de otro. python

Tags: python

Gracias de antemano por la ayuda. 
Soy nuevo en programacion y en python.
Estoy programando un script para bajar subtitulos automáticamente. 
Mi script se fija que videos no tienen subs y guarda los datos en un diccionario, estos datos son:nombre de la serie, la calidad y el grupo que creo el archivo.
Por otra parte, busca en una pagina todos los subtitulo que coinciden con la busqueda de la serie mas el SxxExx. Hasta ahí todo perfecto. 
Ahora tengo dos diccionarios y no sé como hacer para seleccionar la url correcta cuando en la descripción se menciona la calidad y el grupo que aparence en el segundo diccionario.
me dan una mano?

```
dic = {'show':['two and a half men s01e01','the big bang theory s02e03', 'lost s04e08'], 'descripción':['subtitulo por sarasa para la version ntb 720p','por sazra para 1080p dimension','corregidos por dsfsdfsdf para 720p ntb'],'url':['url1','url2','url3']}
dic2 = {'titulo':['two and a half men','the big bang theory', 'lost'], 'calidad':['720p','1080p','480p'],'grupo':['rarbg','ntb','dimension']}
```

**Actualizo:**
Aquí me recomendaron que era más sencillo ordenar los datos en una lista con diccionarios adentro.

```
    lista_ficheros = [{'show': 'young sheldon s02e06', 'calidad': '720p', 'grupo': 'avs'}, 
{'show': 'young sheldon s02e07', 'calidad': '720p', 'grupo': 'avs'}, 
{'show': 'young sheldon s02e08', 'calidad': '720p', 'grupo': 'killers'}, {'show': 'young sheldon s02e09', 'calidad': '720p', 'grupo': 'avs'}
]

lista_servidor = [{'titulo': 'young sheldon s02e06', 'descripcion': 'son los de www subtitulamos tv, pasados espaol latino sirven para las versiones avs/sva', 'url': 'http://www.subdivx.com/bajar.php?id=546948&u=8'}, {'titulo': 'young sheldon s02e06', 'descripcion': 'subtitulo para young sheldon s02e06 1080p web-dl', 'url': 'http://www.subdivx.com/bajar.php?id=546936&u=8'}, {'titulo': 'young sheldon s02e06', 'descripcion': 'subtitulo para young sheldon s02e06 1080p amzn web-dl', 'url': 'http://www.subdivx.com/bajar.php?id=547015&u=8'}, {'titulo': 'young sheldon s02e06', 'descripcion': 'son los de skorpio00, sincronizados para la versin 1080p amzn web-dl ddp5 1 h264-ntb', 'url': 'http://www.subdivx.com/bajar.php?id=549463&u=8'}, {'titulo': 'young sheldon s02e07', 'descripcion': 'son los de www subtitulamos tv, pasados espaol latino sirven para las versiones avs/sva', 'url': 'http://www.subdivx.com/bajar.php?id=547692&u=8'}, {'titulo': 'young sheldon s02e07', 'descripcion': 'de subtitulamos tv - avs / sva / ion10 / ntb / tbs / bamboozle / metcon', 'url': 'http://www.subdivx.com/bajar.php?id=547578&u=8'}, {'titulo': 'young sheldon s02e07', 'descripcion': 'subtitulo para young sheldon s02e07 1080p web-dl', 'url': 'http://www.subdivx.com/bajar.php?id=547586&u=8'}, {'titulo': 'young sheldon s02e07', 'descripcion': 'son los de skorpio00, sincronizados para la versin 1080p amzn web-dl ddp5 1 h 264-ntb', 'url': 'http://www.subdivx.com/bajar.php?id=549464&u=8'}, {'titulo': 'young sheldon s02e08', 'descripcion': 'subtitulo para young sheldon s02e08 1080p metcon', 'url': 'http://www.subdivx.com/bajar.php?id=548309&u=8'}, {'titulo': 'young sheldon s02e08', 'descripcion': 'son los de www subtitulamos tv, pasados espaol latino para las versiones killers ', 'url': 'http://www.subdivx.com/bajar.php?id=548376&u=8'}, {'titulo': 'young sheldon s02e08', 'descripcion': 'subtitulo para young sheldon s02e08 1080p web-dl', 'url': 'http://www.subdivx.com/bajar.php?id=548308&u=8'}, {'titulo': 'young sheldon s02e08', 'descripcion': 'son los de skorpio00, sincronizados para la versin 1080p amzn web-dl ddp5 1 h 264-ntb', 'url': 'http://www.subdivx.com/bajar.php?id=549465&u=8'}, {'titulo': 'young sheldon s02e09', 'descripcion': 'convertidos a espaol neutro por m, de los subttulos de www tusubtitulo com, para las versiones "avs / sva", y algunas otras, saludos  -roargo-', 'url': 'http://www.subdivx.com/bajar.php?id=549306&u=8'}, {'titulo': 'young sheldon s02e09', 'descripcion': 'subtitulo para young sheldon s02e09 1080p metcon', 'url': 'http://www.subdivx.com/bajar.php?id=548900&u=8'}, {'titulo': 'young sheldon s02e09', 'descripcion': 'subtitulo para young sheldon s02e09 1080p web-dl', 'url': 'http://www.subdivx.com/bajar.php?id=548901&u=8'}, {'titulo': 'young sheldon s02e09', 'descripcion': 'son los de www subtitulamos tv, en espaol espaa para las versiones avs/sva', 'url': 'http://www.subdivx.com/bajar.php?id=548974&u=8'}, {'titulo': 'young sheldon s02e09', 'descripcion': 'son los de roargo, sincronizados para la versin 1080p amzn web-dl ddp5 1 h 264-ntb', 'url': 'http://www.subdivx.com/bajar.php?id=549466&u=8'}, {'titulo': 'young sheldon s02e09', 'descripcion': 'young sheldon s02e09  para la versin sva/avs  traduccin original: tonks y jegarvilla (espaol de espaa) crditos: www tusubtitulo com', 'url': 'http://www.subdivx.com/bajar.php?id=549087&u=8'}, {'titulo': 'young sheldon s02e09', 'descripcion': 'de subtitulamos tv - metcon / ion10 / bamboozle', 'url': 'http://www.subdivx.com/bajar.php?id=549194&u=8'}]
```

Para recorrer estas listas utilicé lo siguiente:

```
for i in lista_ficheros:
    calidad = i['calidad']
    grupo = i['grupo']
    titulo = i['show']
    for x in lista_servidor:
        titulo_sv = x['titulo']
        descripcion_sv = x['descripcion']
        url = x['url']
        if titulo in titulo_sv:
            if calidad in descripcion_sv and grupo in descripcion_sv:
                subtitulo_encontrado = True
                print(titulo_sv)
                print(descripcion_sv)
                print(url)
                print('Subtitulo encontrado con la calidad y el grupo exacto')
            if subtitulo_encontrado == False:
                print('No hay ningun subtitulo que contenga el grupo y o  la calidad')
                if titulo in titulo_sv:
                    if calidad in descripcion_sv or grupo in descripcion_sv:
                        subtitulo_encontrado = True
                        print(titulo_sv)
                        print(descripcion_sv)
                        print(url)
                        print('encontre solo con el grupo o calidad')
            else:
                subtitulo_encontrado = False
                print('No hay ningun subtitulo que contenga el grupo y o  la calidad')
```

"andar, anda" como dicen pero hay algo en la lógica que está fallando. Si elimino el último else, que me quedó de las primeras pruebas, la iteración se detiene cuando encuentra el primer subtitulo.

Comment: No me queda claro qué relación hay entre los dos diccionarios y de dónde sale cada uno. Entendí que `dic` sería lo que obtienes de la búsqueda de la página y `dic2` el que resulta de revisar tu carpeta. No tengo claro tampoco qué resultado necesitas de la combinación de esos dos diccionarios ¿puedes poner un ejemplo de la salida deseada?

Comment: También, veo que hay exactamente tres resultados en cada caso, pero aparentemente las urls que estás necesitando no son directamente las 3 que te da el sitio. Entiendo que es posible que entre los resultados del sitio ninguno te valga porque no coincida o la calidad o el grupo. Pero no entiendo bien cómo es que entre los resultados del sitio no aparecen diferentes calidades y grupos para un mismo titulo. ¿Siempre vas a tener un solo resultado por título como en este ejemplo? Si no, ¿puedes poner un ejemplo más realista?

Comment: Finalmente, a lo mejor no necesitas programar nada de esto (salvo que lo estés haciendo por aprender). ¿Conoces [subliminal](https://github.com/Diaoul/subliminal)?

Comment: Buenos días, gracias por la respuesta. Empiezo por lo último: me pareció un buen proyecto para aprender a scrapear webs y practicar otros conceptos.
El primer diccionario, lo obtengo a partir de los archivos de vídeos que tengo en una determinada carpeta.
No sé si necesariamente necesito la "combinación" de ambos diccionarios, simplemente saber si dic2["calidad"][0] (que es 720p) se encuentra en dic['descripcion'][0].
En este caso y a modo de ejemplo, tengo un subtitulo para cada archivo .mkv.

Comment: El problema es que de la pagina que scrapeo la información puedo llegar a tener 30 subtitulos para un mismo archivo de vídeo. Y en la misma carpeta, capaz tengo todos los videos correspondientes a una temporada completa. 
Ahí está mi problema, dónde no sé como iterar a través de  los diccionarios para que me encuentre, en la descripción del primer diccionario, uno que coincida la calidad y el grupo a partir del segundo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si entendí correctamente, el siguiente código haría lo que buscas:

```
for i, titulo in enumerate(dic2['titulo']):
  if (dic2['calidad'][i] in dic['descripción'][i]
      and dic2['grupo'][i] in dic['descripción'][i]):
    print("{} --> URL: {}".format(titulo, dic['url'][i]))
  else:
    print("{} --> No aparece en la calidad y grupo adecuados".format(titulo))
```

Se trata de verificar, para cada elemento de las listas, si la calidad **y** el grupo figuran ambos en la descripción. Si es así, se imprime la correspondiente URL, y si no el mensaje de que no se encuentra.

Si ejecutamos ese código sobre los datos que suministras:

```
dic = {'show':['two and a half men s01e01','the big bang theory s02e03', 'lost s04e08'], 'descripción':['subtitulo por sarasa para la version ntb 720p','por sazra para 1080p dimension','corregidos por dsfsdfsdf para 720p ntb'],'url':['url1','url2','url3']}
dic2 = {'titulo':['two and a half men','the big bang theory', 'lost'], 'calidad':['720p','1080p','480p'],'grupo':['rarbg','ntb','dimension']}
```

Sale en este caso que no ha encontrado nada:

```
two and a half men --> No aparece en la calidad y grupo adecuados
the big bang theory --> No aparece en la calidad y grupo adecuados
lost --> No aparece en la calidad y grupo adecuados
```

No tengo aún clara (después de leer tus comentarios) qué estructura tendría el diccionario `dic` en caso de que un mismo título pueda aparecer con diferentes calidades, o grupos. Entiendo que en ese caso los dos diccionarios se "desincronizan" por decirlo de algún modo, ya que la lista del `dic2` son los ficheros que tú tienes (digamos 3 en este ejemplo) mientras que `dic` sería la lista de resultados, que puede ser mucho más larga, y por tanto deja de ser cierto que el elemento `[i]` en ambas listas corresponda a un mismo título.

¿Podrías poner un ejemplo de cómo sería un caso así?

Por otro lado, si estos diccionarios los estás creando tú, quizás haya otra forma más sencilla de crearlos y procesarlos. Por ejemplo ¿y si en lugar de tener un diccionario cuyos campos contienen listas, creas una lista cuyos elementos son diccionarios? Es decir:

```
lista_servidor = [
     {'descripción': 'subtitulo por sarasa para la version ntb 720p',
      'show': 'two and a half men s01e01',
      'url': 'url1'},
     {'descripción': 'por sazra para 1080p dimension',
      'show': 'the big bang theory s02e03',
      'url': 'url2'},
     {'descripción': 'corregidos por dsfsdfsdf para 720p ntb',
      'show': 'lost s04e08',
      'url': 'url3'}]
lista_ficheros = [
     {'calidad': '720p', 'grupo': 'rarbg', 'titulo': 'two and a half men'},
     {'calidad': '1080p', 'grupo': 'ntb', 'titulo': 'the big bang theory'},
     {'calidad': '480p', 'grupo': 'dimension', 'titulo': 'lost'}]
```

En mi opinión, esta otra forma de almacenar la información haría más sencillo procesarlo luego.

## Actualización

El usuario ha editado la pregunta añadiendo nueva información, con un caso real de qué contendrían estas listas.

Creo que, ya que en principio cualquiera de las películas en tu carpeta podría generar más de un "resultado positivo" en el servidor, lo lógico sería crear listas con esos resultados. Esto es más importante aún en el caso de querer mostrar también los "resultados aproximados", en los que o bien coincide la calidad o bien el grupo. En estos casos también puede haber varios resultados.

El algoritmo podría basarse en el que tú has puesto en el que, por cada película de la carpeta se busca la misma entre las reportadas por el servidor, pero en lugar de imprimir directamente lo que se vaya encontrando, se va guardando en tres listas: una que contenga las coincidencias "exactas" (calidad y grupo), otra sólo las que coincidan con calidad, y otra sólo las que coincida el grupo. La parte que busca una película en los resultados del servidor y que construye estas tres listas, puede extraerse a una función para simplificar el código.

El programa principal haría un bucle en el que llamaría a esa función para cada película de la carpeta, y recogería las tres listas (resultados exactos, con calidad y con grupo) que la función retorna. Entonces bastarán unos `if` para ver cuáles de esas listas contienen algo, para imprimir sus contenidos de una forma adecuada. Para imprimirlo he preferido crear otra función.

Estas serían las funciones para buscar una película entre los resultados del servidor y para imprimir una lista de resultados:

```
def buscar_resultados(elemento, lista_servidor):
    calidad = elemento['calidad']
    grupo = elemento['grupo']
    titulo = elemento['show']
    print("Buscando '{}'".format(titulo))
    exacto = []
    con_calidad = []
    con_grupo = []
    for x in lista_servidor:
        titulo_sv = x['titulo']
        descripcion_sv = x['descripcion']
        url = x['url']
        if titulo not in titulo_sv:
            continue
        if calidad in descripcion_sv and grupo in descripcion_sv:
            exacto.append(x)
        if calidad in descripcion_sv:
            con_calidad.append(x)
        if grupo in descripcion_sv:
            con_grupo.append(x)
    # Retornar las tres listas halladas
    return exacto, con_calidad, con_grupo

def mostrar_resultados(lista):
  for elemento in lista:
    print("  *", elemento["descripcion"])
    print("   ", elemento["url"])
```

Ahora el "programa principal" quedaría así:

```
for elemento in lista_ficheros:
    exacto, con_calidad, con_grupo = buscar_resultados(elemento, lista_servidor)
    if exacto:
        print("Encontrado exacto:")
        mostrar_resultados(exacto)
    elif con_calidad or con_grupo:
        if con_calidad:
            print("Encontrados con la calidad adecuada:")
            mostrar_resultados(con_calidad)
        if con_grupo:
            print("Encontrados con el grupo adecuado:")
            mostrar_resultados(con_grupo)
    else:
        print("No se ha encontrado ni grupo ni calidad")
    print("-----------")
```

Que al ejecutarse mostrará algo como esto (no muestro todo):

```html
Buscando 'young sheldon s02e06'
Encontrados con el grupo adecuado:
  * son los de www subtitulamos tv, pasados espaol latino sirven para las versiones avs/sva
    http://www.subdivx.com/bajar.php?id=546948&u=8
-----------
Buscando 'young sheldon s02e07'
Encontrados con el grupo adecuado:
  * son los de www subtitulamos tv, pasados espaol latino sirven para las versiones avs/sva
    http://www.subdivx.com/bajar.php?id=547692&u=8
  * de subtitulamos tv - avs / sva / ion10 / ntb / tbs / bamboozle / metcon
    http://www.subdivx.com/bajar.php?id=547578&u=8
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. 
Es como vos decís, los diccionarios siempre se terminan "desincronizando" ya que el diccionario que me devuelve la web, suele ser mucho más grande que el que yo generé a partir de mis archivos.
Tu forma de almacenar es mucho mejor que la mía, voy a tratar de modificar eso en mi código.
Ahora pruebo y vuelvo a escribir.

Comment: @abulafia, por que esta pregunta se muestra como opaca ?

Comment: @Mystic_Force No sé a qué te refieres. Tanto la pregunta como la respuesta las veo normales.

Comment: Bueno, probé haciendo lo que me recomendás: cambie los diccionarios con listas por listas con diccionarios. Actualizo la pregunta original.

Comment: @DiegoEsperguin Actualizo la respuesta

Comment: Excelente respuesta, muchas gracias!! @abulafia